# Searching multiple tables on the same sheet with the column in varying locations and copying them to a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Hopefully the title is clear. I am trying to search through multiple tables on a single sheet. The information I am looking for is the same for all of the tables, just that the corresponding column is located in different spots (e.g. in one table the column I want to search is in I, while for another table it could be in O.) which makes it a bit more challenging for me.

I want to search through each column that has the same title (Load Number) and depending on its value, copy that entire row over to a sheet that corresponds with that value.

Below is what I have so far in VBA as well as a picture to hopefully clarify my issue.

Any help/advice is appreciated!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ph3rb.jpg

```
    Sub Load_Number_Finder()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

j = 1

Set ws = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Master"))
ws.Name = ("Test Load " & j)

i = 1
Sheets("Master").Select
For Each cell In Sheets("Master").Range("M:M")
If cell.Value = "1" Then
j = 1
'Set WS = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Master"))
'WS.Name = ("Test Load " & j)
    matchRow = cell.Row
    Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
    Selection.Copy

    Sheets("Test Load " & j).Select
    ActiveSheet.Rows(i).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Master").Select
    i = i + 1

ElseIf cell.Value = "" Then
' 2, 3, 4, 5, cases

Else
' Something needs to go here to catch when it doesnt have a load number on it yet


End If

' Err_Execute:
'    MsgBox "An error occurred."
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I need a clearer idea of what you want to do and I can help you. Also can you provide me with a picture of the entire worksheet. Knowing the entire structure helps a lot. First, are you searching based on the first column (an ID)? Secondly, you want to copy/paste the entire row corresponding with the ID to another sheet? So you want to find all rows corresponding with an ID and then depending on the value copy/paste. You need to clarify these things. Also as an aside, this is not a way to efficiently use Excel's environment.

Comment: The worksheet itself contains multiple tables and can get pretty long. I am searching based on values in the "LD #" column, which is in different columns depending on the table. I am trying to search that column for a number (usually just 1-10), and then depending on that value, I want to copy over that entire row to a Load List sheet that corresponds with the value found in "LD #"

Comment: Ok so LD# is your identifier. Then based on that value, you want to copy/paste the entire row? SO in your other sheet you will have a collection of rows of varying length corresponding with the LD# from the master sheet?

Comment: Can you update the photo please. It would really help.

Comment: I don't see the LD# column here. I really need to know the structure of your worksheet in order to write a code for it.

Comment: Linked the sheet to IMGUR... didnt mess up the format this way. let me know if that works

Comment: and to your question starting with LD # being the identifier, yes I believe you understand what I am asking

Comment: Ok that's a lot better. So the main challenge in this macro is to determine where we need to stop parsing the different LD#. Imagine this, you find the header LD#, now you want to read all the numbers below it until the next table. However, the computer needs a way to determine when it has reached a new table. At first I was going to suggest when we see "Qty" in the first column, but that changes to "Color", "Co" and "Mark". Then I thought we can use the titles of the Tables. If you have an exhaustive list of what all the possible table headers can be we can use those. Do you?

Comment: The best way would be to add an identifier that tells you when a new table is starting. Maybe in the header make it. Table: Tiles, Table: Main Frames, etc... Then you can identify when you have reached a new Table by reading the first column and seeing if the String "Table" appears.

Comment: Or is it a guarantee that every single table will have a LD# column. If you have a column that will always be there, we can use its header title to identify a new row as well.

Comment: the sheet I sent you should have all the cases included as to what header could possibly be under or on top of LD #

Comment: and yes, LD # will be included in all of the tables

Comment: Ok give me a few minutes.

Comment: no rush. Also, as shown in the picture, LD # can potentially have multiple values in it.. so another unique facet that makes this problem challenging haha... and need a dynamic range of sheets to paste to depending on how many different Loads there are!!  My brains starts going in circles the more I think about it haha

Comment: That's no problem. Are the LD# values like 1,2,3,4,5,... always. Is there a range? Can it be negative or 0?

Comment: What does it mean when they have multiple values like "2 3". Do you want the whole row copy/pasted into both sheet 2 and 3?

Comment: yes, exactly.. in that case part of the quantity could be in multiple loads so want it copied to both.

Comment: and it will always be a positive, non-zero integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function. This should work for you. Let me know what the results are with your sheet. I made a mock up sheet and tested it, it worked. I can make changes if this is not exactly what you are looking for.

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyPaste()
    Dim rowCount, row_ix, temp, i As Integer
    Dim TD_COL_IX As Integer
    Dim td_value As String
    Dim td_values() As String

    rowCount = Worksheets("Master").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For row_ix = 1 To rowCount

        temp = isNewTable(CInt(row_ix))
        If temp > 0 Then

            TD_COL_IX = temp

        ElseIf TD_COL_IX > 0 Then

            td_value = Worksheets("Master").Cells(row_ix, TD_COL_IX)
            If Not td_value = "" Then
                td_values = Split(td_value, " ")
                For i = 0 To UBound(td_values)

                    If Not sheetExists("Test Load " & td_values(i)) Then
                        Sheets.Add.Name = "Test Load " & td_values(i)
                    End If

                    If Worksheets("Test Load " & td_values(i)).Cells(1, 1).Value = "" Then
                        Worksheets("Master").Range(Worksheets("Master").Cells(row_ix, 1), Worksheets("Master").Cells(row_ix, TD_COL_IX - 1)).Copy _
                            Destination:=Worksheets("Test Load " & td_values(i)).Cells(1, 1)
                    Else
                        Dim rowCount_pasteSheet As Integer
                        rowCount_pasteSheet = Worksheets("Test Load " & td_values(i)).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

                        Worksheets("Master").Range(Worksheets("Master").Cells(row_ix, 1), Worksheets("Master").Cells(row_ix, TD_COL_IX - 1)).Copy _
                            Destination:=Worksheets("Test Load " & td_values(i)).Cells(rowCount_pasteSheet + 1, 1)
                    End If
                Next i
            End If
        End If
    Next row_ix
End Sub


Function isNewTable(row_ix As Integer) As Integer
    Dim colCount, col_ix As Integer

    colCount = Worksheets("Master").Cells(row_ix, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For col_ix = 1 To colCount

        If Not IsError(Worksheets("Master").Cells(row_ix, col_ix).Value) Then
            If Worksheets("Master").Cells(row_ix, col_ix).Value = "LD #" Then
                isNewTable = col_ix
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next col_ix

    isNewTable = 0
End Function



' ####################################################
' sheetExists(sheetToFind As String) As Boolean
'
' Returns true if the sheet exists, False otherwise
' ####################################################
Public Function sheetExists(sheetToFind As String) As Boolean
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    sheetExists = False
    For Each sheet In Worksheets
        If sheetToFind = sheet.Name Then
            sheetExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next sheet
End Function
```

Comment: Great, thank you! I will give it a test run and let you know how it goes.

Comment: threw a "type mismatch" and pointed to this line:                                                If Worksheets("Master").Cells(row_ix, col_ix).Value = "LD#" Then

Comment: Although I don't think this is why that error message was thrown, but should be worth mentioning that each cell in LD # may not have a value in it, when it does have a value it will always be a positive non-zero integer, but it is also possible it can be blank (like in the provided picture)

Comment: add a space to LD# such that it is "LD #". This statement looks at what is in a specific cell, and compares it to "LD #", to see if that is what it is.

Comment: The error might be caused by your top stuff. If what is inside the cell is not usual. What row do you start your tables?

Comment: thank you. and row 6 is where the first table starts

Comment: Try this, I changed it now. It's strange because I was unable to reproduce your error albeit having almost the same tables as you. All I am missing is the top matter. But, now it will disregard it.

Comment: Right above the line that's giving an error. Put: MsgBox Worksheets("Master").Cells(row_ix, col_ix).Value

Comment: What does it say?

Comment: it says MAIN FRAMES

Comment: And right after there is an error?? What is the last message that pops up before the error occurs?

Comment: yea many boxes come up before it throws the error. Also, just changed it cuz i realized there are 3 spaces inbetween LD and # haha.. even after changing it for that it still throws the error. and there are a lot of boxes that appear before it throws the error now so may take me a few times running it to see exactly where the error is thrown

Comment: the message box is blank before the error is thrown. and now the line that is highlighted when it is thrown is the msgbox line

Comment: row ix is 18 and col ix is 8 when the error is thrown, if that helps. I commented out the message box part and the same line as before gets highlighted

Comment: Ok I believe the error was caused by the #DIV error. Try the new code I just added. Make sure not to forget to change the "LD #" to have th eappropriate number of spaces.

Comment: EUREKA! ran through without an error :)... havent tried multiple numbers in  a cell yet.. also, when it copies over, it doesnt include that LD # column, which im guessing could be easily included.

Comment: You want the LD# column too? But sometimes it has multiple values and it seems kind of useless since the sheet tells you what load you are talking about. Right? I can add it in, just tell me how to deal with the multiple load numbers, do you want them all copy/pasted, or just the corresponding one?

Comment: so, any cell that has two load numbers will also have two numbers in the "QTY" column, ideally I'd like just the corresponding values to be shown in both places.

Comment: And I really appreciate everything and havent tried doing it myself yet and am happy to do so, but would it be a pain to also grab each title of the tables to still have them sort of broken up on the "Test Load" pages

Comment: Do you want to headers only (Qty, description, etc..) or the title as well (Tiles, Main Frame, etc...)

Comment: both of them would be ideal

Comment: How come in your example, I don;t see the Qty having two numbers if the LD# has 2 numbers?

Comment: I quickly just added the quantities into the LD # without doing the same for the quantity... and im sorry, it ISN'T the "QTY" column that would have multiple corresponding values to the multiple values in the "LD   #" column it is the "QTY SHIP" column. apologies

Comment: so if "LD   #" read "1 2", then the cell in the same row under "QTY SHIP" would read something like "50 50"

Comment: and the values are simply seperated by a space... no comma or any other sort of delimiter besides for the space

Comment: Nevermind the multiple values in a cell. What would be the most efficient way to just include the title and headings of the column?